# Next js Sitemap static export

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, sitemap

I need help building a Sitemap for my NextJs project.
I build a headless cms using graphql and next, however, everything is statically generated.
I'm having a lot of issues creating a sitemap. I tried using the npm next-sitemap but all the info I find (youtube and forums) are for projects containing "serversideprops", when my project only contains "getStaticProps" and getStaticPaths. In addition to that I also require the map to handle dynamic paths [slug].js. ** I'm not using typescript

Here is what part of my [slug].js looks like:

graphql query....

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {   
    const { posts } = await graphcms.request(SLUGLIST);   
    return {
        paths: posts.map((post) => ({ params: { slug: post.slug } })),
        fallback: false,   
    }; 
}
     
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {   
    const slug = params.slug;   
    const data = await graphcms.request(QUERY, { slug });  
    const { posts } = await graphcms.request(QUERY2);   
    const post = data.post;   
    return {
        props: {
            post,
            posts,
        },   
    }; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next-sitemap` also creates the routes based on the static pages you generate. The thing is you have to run it **after** you generated your project.

Typically, you should have a configuration file like this at the base of your project:

`next-sitemap.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next-sitemap').IConfig} */
module.exports = {
  siteUrl: process.env.VERCEL_URL ? `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}` : 'https://my-fallback-url.com/',
  generateRobotsTxt: true,
  trailingSlash: true,
  targetDirectory: `${__dirname}/public`,
  // Wherever are your pages stored
  pagesDirectory: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
};
```

and on your `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    ... other configurations
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap"
  },
```

Which will trigger `next-sitemap` after your build is complete. You should then find all the generated `xml` files containing your sitemap.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a question about the " siteUrl: process.env.VERCEL_URL ? `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}` : 'https://my-fallback-url.com/'," Should I change it to anything else? Do i have to use vercel for it yo work?

Comment: Since you were using NextJs I blindly assumed you would host it on Vercel. But of course you can use any other environment variable

Comment: thanks for your comment. I'm not using versel. I'm still trying to wrap my mind around the "my-fallback-url.com". Would it be a 404 pack? I read the documentation for next-sitemap and they suggest you use www.example.com, but I'm not sure what to use exactly...

Comment: Just use the url where your website is located and you should be good to go

Comment: Your solution worked! Thanks a bunch for helping. Been trying for weeks to build this map ugh!